# Elementary OS reset session after screen lock or suspend

Tags: session, settings, elementary-os

If change main screen in system settings - it may happen, that locking of screen of suspend of system will require to authenticate twice (first authenticate will restart login screen) and after second authentication you will see clear session. It will be possible to see in file `/var/log/syslog` lines, where `gala` is restarting due to impossibility to find the display to show

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to fix it is to remove monitors config:

`$ rm ~/.config/monitors.xml*`

And restart system.